# How to give user choose folder option while downloading file in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am building a desktop app using javafx. I need to download a file from FTP.
I want before downloading the user should be prompted with the windows/mac explorer window to choose the download location.
How can I achieve this in Javafx ??

I am downloading the file on the click of an button so I am using it inside my controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose a file with a [`FileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) or choose a directory with a [`DirectoryChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html).

E.g.

```
DirectoryChooser dirChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
File chosenDir = dirChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);
```

Comment: I am using it on the click of a button, so I am using it inside my controller class in initialize method. How can I use it here because I don't have Stage variable there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491732/how-do-i-open-the-javafx-filechooser-from-a-controller-class'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DirectoryChoser?
It opens an OS native dialog to select a directory, and returns it as a File object.
If you want to create a new file, you can read the Path of the selected directory, append a file name and create the new File object you want to save.
For example:

```
    DirectoryChooser dirChooser = new DirectoryChooser();

    dirChooser.setTitle("Select a folder");

    File selectedDir = dirChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);

    String selectedDirPath = dirChooser.showDialog(mainApp.getPrimaryStage()).getAbsolutePath();

    File downloadedFile = new File(selectedDirPath + "/" + downloadedFileName);
```